# Secure mobile apps connection to server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web, mobile

I'm creating a mobile application using web technologies such as Java Script. My server is running php to connect to database. If I want to Insert/Delete/Update something in database, information needs to be passed by Ajax. I know that no one can see source code when using the app, but if somehow someone can get the source code, how can I prevent from user to see my server address and php file name?

Sample Code (from w3schools):

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way

```
    <div id="testeFuncao">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#butaoTeste").on("click", function(){
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            });

            $("#testeFuncao").remove();
        </script>
    </div>
```